# CSS validation: "Parse Error: @keyframes"

Tags: css, media-queries, css-animations, w3c-validation

When I tried to validate my website, the W3C CSS Validator says parse error. I really tried to understand what I had done wrong but I could really need some help.

This is what the validator says:

> Parse Error: `@keyframes line_draw{ 100%{ width: 100vh; } }`

And this is the code in the file:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) { 
  @keyframes line_draw{ 
    100%{ width: 100vh;} 
  }
```

Comment: I tried the css validator on your input, it is correct. https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input+with_options Are you sure you're giving the same input to the css validator?

Comment: Oh I see! When I validate the entire code the Parse error comes up but not on this small part. Why is that? I just copied the part that the validator said was wrong.  Would it help if you had the rest as well?

Comment: I can't find a parse error in valid css.. The best would be to try and remove lines that work until you find the part that does not work.

Comment: I deleted everything but the line that the validator said was wrong and the media queries, so the error is somwhere here: 

`@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {

 @keyframes line_draw{
  100%{width: 100vh;}
 }
`

Comment: That's *very* different from the code you originally provided. This is why you should only provide the code that actually triggers the parse error, rather than some other code you started out with, although providing background context *helps*.

Comment: This appears to be a known bug of the CSS validator: https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/44

Answer (score 2):

As @BoltClock said, it seems like IE just doesn't recognize `@keyframes` inside `@media` rules. But you can just create two different `@keyframes` and change the `animation-name` property inside a `@media` rule, as follows:

```
@keyframes line_draw {
    100% {
        width: 100vh;
    }
}

@keyframes line_draw_smaller_screen {
    100% {
        width: 100vh;
    }
}

#yourElement {
    animation: line_draw 2s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {

    #yourElement {
        animation-name: line_draw_smaller_screen;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the validator doesn't recognize `@keyframes` rules in `@media` rules. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#nested_statement) allows this, and it clearly works on all browsers.

If the parse error bothers you enough (for example because you need to validate often and it keeps getting in the way), you can work around this by swapping `animation-name`s instead of keyframe rules in your `@media` rules, which also resolves the issue of [Internet Explorer not supporting `@keyframes` rules nested in `@media` rules anyway](https://nooshu.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/media-query-keyframes).